# Static variable link error in MSVC even though it is created in the cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I am working on a cross-platform (Linux & Windows) library. One of my class has a static member defined in the header. And I created it in a CPP file like

```
namespace raisim {
std::function<void()> RaiSimMsg::fatalCallback_ = []() { exit(1); };
}
```

The header file

```
#ifndef RAISIM_MESSAGE_LOGGER_HPP
#define RAISIM_MESSAGE_LOGGER_HPP

#include <chrono>
...

namespace raisim {

class RaiSimMsg {
 public:
  ...
  void stream(const char *file, const int line, std::stringstream &msg, int severity) {
    if (severity == RSEVERITY_FATAL)
      fatalCallback_();
  }


 private:
   static std::function<void()> fatalCallback_;
};


}

#endif //RAISIM_MESSAGE_LOGGER_HPP
```

This works perfectly with GCC and Clang in Linux. But MSVC is giving a link error. Does MSVC have its own rules for static members??

Full error log

```
1>anymal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::function<void __cdecl(void)> raisim::RaiSimMsg::fatalCallback_" (?fatalCallback_@RaiSimMsg@raisim@@0V?$function@$$A6AXXZ@std@@A)
1>C:\Users\ultrafrog\source\repos\raisim\build\benchmark\Debug\speed_test_anymal.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "speed_test_anymal.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Not sure how this can help but I added the full log from Visual Studio

Comment: We need to see: (a) the header prototype, (b) the .cpp implementation (at least the entry-point), and (c) the call-site where you are calling this function. My suspicion is that you don't have consistent calling convention annotations, but I'm not sure from this.

Comment: (a) I added it above. (b) the cpp file is as is above. It only has a couple of #includes (c) the function is called inside the method defined in the header file as above

Comment: A quick test that might be useful in this situation: in just the CPP file with the definition (**not in the header file**), change the name from `fatalCallback_` to either `fatalCallback_Z` or `IWantACompilerError`. This should trigger a compiler error when you build your project. If it doesn't, you failed to add this file to your project, hence it didn't get linked in.

Comment: Yes, that triggered a compiler error. This is working code in GCC and Clang so I doubt that there is a typo

Comment: What is SO? The original namespace is raisim but I just wanted to make it look generic. They have the same namespace

Comment: @ultrafrog Are you saying that GCC and Clang are using `speed_test_anymal.vcxproj` to build your project? I thought that was a MS-specific extension and other compilers would use different project files. If they are using different project files, then the possibility of a mistake in the MS project file should not so easily dismissed.

Comment: SO == [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). You might be familiar with it? ;)

Comment: No, they are created from the same CMakeLists.txt. There are a few compiler-specific cmake command but not relevant ones

Comment: It seems very clear to me, the CPP file that provides the implementation of `fatalCallback_` is not being linked.

Comment: @MarkRansom I figured out that that is the case. I manually copied the dlls and the link was gone. I guess the way they link libraries in Windows is very different.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. I cannot even create dll. I commented the function call during testing and that's how it was working. It seems like a bug in MSVC but I will investigate it further then post an answer myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jack Dingler's answer here

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/585271/Aplusstaticplusmemberplusvariableplusexportpluserr

worked. So the issue is that the Windows linker needs to know that if it has to import or export the symbol. So we have to declare `__declspec(dllexport)` when we export (when we build the library) and  `__declspec(dllimport)` for using it. We can switch that using a compilation flag. I am not sure why they designed the linker like this but anyway it works now.